# What do I connect the ground and power symbols in this schematic to?

Tags: power

There are 5 grounds and 3 power source (12V).

[image]

I bought a 12V and 1A wall adapter. It has a plus and minus end. Can I connect the other 2 12V sources in parallel. Will the reduction in current affect this device.

[image]

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312284/why-do-i-not-fry-a-gpu-when-its-pcie-power-is-connected-to-a-second-psu/312300?noredirect=1#comment727100_312300 if you share, its best to guarantee voltage matching or add Schottky diodes in each line.

Comment: Yes it will. You cannot run this circuit with a 1A power supply. You need one with at least 6 amps capacity and more would be better.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, is there any danger in using that adapter? The guy who built this told me I can use it.

Comment: @user132522 - Sure you can "use" it, and if it's decently made it won't catch fire immediately. What it won't do is activate your magnet. The output voltage will fall to nearly zero and will probably oscillate. On second thought, it may well overheat. As for catching fire, I can't tell.

Answer (score 3):

> There are 5 grounds and 3 power source (12V).

Generally you connect all grounds together.

You also can connect the 12 V lines together but in this case you have a very high powered electro-magnet. The current draw and switching noise from this may cause interference in the rest of your circuit.

> I bought a 12V and 1A wall adapter. It has a plus and minus end. Can I connect the other 2 12V sources in parallel. Will the reduction in current affect this device.

There won't be a reduction in current by paralleling devices. There will be an increase - and a large one.

From Ohm's law you can see that the current is given by \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {12}{2} = 6 \; A \$.

Your 1 A power supply hasn't a hope of driving this.

Comment: Is 6 the total current? How do you know the total resistance is 2 ohm? There are other resistors here.

Comment: I've given you the formula so you should be able to calculate these yourself. The LED resistor will have about 10 V across it. The 68 and 820 are in series so calculate the current for the pair of them as one 888 Ω resistor.

Comment: @user132522 the big current path is from 12V, through the electromagnet (specified as 2 ohms), through the BUZ31L (very low resistance when switched on), to ground.  The other paths will draw a lot less current.

Comment: @SimonB, is that e magnet networth along with the MOSFET, in parallel with the 820ohm resistor? What do you think is the purpose of the 820 resistor since it drew little current?

Comment: The 820 Ω resistor discharges the gate of the MOSFET to turn it off quickly.

Answer (score 1):

2 OHM DCR of magnet coil indicates the current demands 6 A on startup until moving then max current when stopped.

So your source must be capable of at least 6A or 72W  plus 25% margin.  Use an ATX PSU.

Comment: No way ATX looks huge.